# TextArea in Flex 4.6 on Android not showing

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, textarea, flex4.6

My Text Areas sometimes show sometimes dont, if I go to screen saver and back then they show.

Any ideas how to get ride o this behavior?

Regards
Craig